# SQL Server DATEDIFF results in overflow on day comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server

Got a slight issue, I've got a view with several hundred thousand rows (and only going to get exponentially bigger) with a column with a datetime like so: `2017-07-10 12:13:46.000`.

I'm trying to only select items with a timestamp in the last 7 days. I've got this:

```
SELECT Top(100) * FROM vw_dataList
WHERE DATEDIFF( DAY, vw_dataList.startTime, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) < 7;
```

But this results in an error:

> The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff with a less precise datepart.

I'm not really sure why this is, as even if DATEDIFF creates an integer from the timestamp, it shouldn't be such a big integer as to cause an overflow should it? Not really sure where to go from here so any advice is appreciated!

Cheers!

Comment: What is the output when you select only today or only yesterday?

Comment: It's the same no matter what the number

Comment: Even if you have no number so the day is current_timestamp?

Comment: Are your dates significantly far in the past/future?

Comment: Seems that the plan for this query will be better if you use  WHERE vw_dataList.startTime > GETDATE() - 7, as you commented that the size is of your table is too big, you can also insert a index in this column that probably won't be used with DATEDIFF() function.

Comment: Judging from the `vw_` prefix, you are selecting from a view. Maybe the error is in the code for the view?

Comment: @RogérioCarvalho That works! If you can put it in an answer that'd be great :)

Comment: `DATEDIFF(DAY,'0001-01-01', '9999-12-31')` returns a result. And these are the min and max possible dates. So probably this is coming from a `DATEDIFF` inside the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the plan for this query will be better if you use:

```
WHERE w_dataList.startTime > GETDATE() - 7
```

As you commented that the size of your table is too big, you can also insert a index in this column that probably won't be used with DATEDIFF() function.

Index sample:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_dataList ON vw_dataList (startTime DESC);
```

PS: Seems that it is a view, so you should replace the view to insert it in your table.

PS2: Check if you really need this index, you can check it in the execution plan.

Comment: @Compy, glad you found a solution. If I were you I'd still try to find what caused the error in the first place. As Martin Smith observed, you shouldn't get this error at all.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a date in your table that is significantly far in the past or future that is causing the `DATEDIFF` function to overflow. That function returns a signed integer so any date that is 2 billion (give or take) days in the future or past will overflow.

One option is to not use [`DATEDIFF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql) at all and instead use [`DATEADD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql) subtract 7 days from the current time and use that to compare:

```
SELECT TOP(100) * 
FROM vw_dataList
WHERE vw_dataList.startTime >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

A possible alternative, though I wouldn't recomment it in this situation is to use [`DATEDIFF_BIG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-big-transact-sql) as this returns a `BIGINT`.

Comment: The entire range of dates supported is only 3,652,058 days - this is significantly less than 2 billion.